# Redirect to dashboard after login [EMBER.JS]

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js, authentication, ember-cli

I want to redirect after login to the user dashboard, how could I do this? Currently I have a registration page and login page, but after logging it back to the home page where the login and the registration, I want it to go to dashboard, needing any file I post here

---

UPDATE:

**controller/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
   invalidateSession() {
     this.get('session').invalidate();
 }
}
});
```

**controller/login.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
  authenticate() {
  let { identification, password } = 
this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
  this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', 
identification, password).catch((reason) => {
    this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
  });
 }
 }
});
```

**route/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
 import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-
auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
 actions: {
  invalidateSession() {
  this.get('session').invalidate();
 }
}

});
```

**route/login.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `routeAfterAuthentication` to your Application route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {

  routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',

  actions: {
    invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/ApplicationRouteMixin.html

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you send login/pass to the backend, you can use the promise success callback to redirect with something like:

somewhere in your route (application route or login route):

```
actions: {
   checkAuth(email, password) {
     let _this = this;
     // Ajax call or service call
     .....authenticate(email, password).then(function(data) {
       // set current user
       // do whatever you want
       _this.transitionTo("dashboard"); // redirect to the dashboard route
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share some part where you authenticate the user in a [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) please ?